# Реализация default интерфейсов

Tags: java, интерфейс

Есть некоторый интерфейс

```
interface Base {
  ........
}
```

Есть его реализация

```
class BaseImpl implements Base {
  ........
}
```

и есть наследник интерфейса у которого есть **только** default методы

```
interface Child extends Base {
  default .....
}
```

Мне нужно вызвать методы `Child` имея экземпляр класса `BaseImpl`.

Можно ли как-то объекты `BaseImpl` привести к `Child` или нужно только писать наследника

```
class ChildImpl extends BaseImpl implements Child {}
```

Comment: Вы можете использовать вместо методов Base внутри Child другие defaul методы, которые будут не обязательны для переопределения внутри класса. Либо, сдлайте абстрактный класс, который будет наследовать оба интерфейса, а вы в своем классе ChildImpl просто будете использовать нужный метод

Comment: @Dred Вы не совсем поняли вопрос. Я наоборот хочу избавиться от `ChildImpl`. Мне нужно вызвать методы `Child` имея экземпляр класса `BaseImpl`.

Comment: `Java` поддерживает множественное наследование интерфейсов, в чем проблема в одном классе юзать?

Comment: @And `BaseImpl` не мой. И наследуюсь я от чужого интерфейса

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, так, а теперь поподробней, пожалуйста. Если `BaseImpl` не ваш, то как вы можете использовать методы Child в экземляре `BaseImpl`? А интерфейс хоть `Base` ваш?

Comment: @Dred в интерфейсе Child объявлены только default методы. Которые сами используют методы интерфейса Base. BaseImpl реализует интерфейс Base. Я хочу получить что-то типа такого `Child child = (Child)(new BaseImpl())`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, в таком случае, видимо, если вы можете использовать только `super` методы, тогда ваш вариант единственный

Comment: @AntonShchyrov так вот и получается в Java: чтобы не связываться с вагоном `extends`-`implements`, для своих интерфейсов и классов extension-методы приходится писать в самих интерфейсах/классах, а для сторонних - Helper-классы...

Comment: То что вы хотите сделать, нельзя реализовать. Как родитель может стать ребенком, если он даже не знает о ребенке нечего?)))

Comment: Если он не ваш, то значит, сделать этого никак нельзя без наследования и переопределения методов, однозначно. Хотя, если использовать некий динамический конструктор, как-то взять инфу, возможно, может-быть и можно, но будет это как минимум геморно, так-как, - это находится не в одной области видимости..

Comment: @And методы переопределять не нужно. Что-то на основании анонимных классов нельзя придумать?

Comment: А причем тут анонимные классы, если импорт происходит со стороны? И про переопределения я до кучи добавил. И анонимный и есть интерфейс =)

Comment: @And Что-то типа `Child child = new BaseImpl() implements Child {}`

Comment: Вы серьезно? Вы хотите внедрить стороннему классу интерфейс? На секунду, представьте, чтоб бы было, если-бы так можно было... Жиесть.

Comment: @And И в чем криминал? Я создаю наследника. То, что он анонимный - особой роли не играет